# get value from Text('value') in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
   List<Widget> tabs = [
      Tab(text: 'a'),
      Tab(text: 'b'),
      Tab(text: 'c),
      Tab(text: 'd'),
    ];

              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(
                  'category',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
                ),
                centerTitle: false,
                bottom: TabBar(
                  isScrollable: true,
                  tabs: tabs, // here used
                ),
              )


 for (var tab in tabs)
   Text(tab.getText) <-- I want to put text value (a, b, c, d) here
```

I am javascript developer and just diving into flutter.

I want to make one array or object array and reuse that. 
Is there a way to pop the (text: 'a') ?

Thank you for advice this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a list of tab widget, create a list of Strings and map through them to crate your tabs

```
List<String> tabTexts = [
  'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
];


appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text(
    'category',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11),
  ),
  centerTitle: false,
  bottom: TabBar(
    isScrollable: true,
    tabs: tabTexts.map((text) {
      return Tab(text: text,);
    }).toList(), // here used
  ),
)
```

Now you can reuse your `tabTexts`

```
for (var tabText in tabTexts)
Text(tabText)
```

Comment: I got error that represents The argument type 'Iterable<Tab>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.

so I changed to 

<Widget>[tabs.map((tab) {
                  return Tab(text: tab);
                  })]

The element type 'Iterable<Tab>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. error appeared.

Comment: @DanielLee It should be converted to a list using `toList()`. Updated my answer, have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `Tab` is custom class from you. If the field `text` is public, then you should be able to access it as follows:

```dart
class Tab {
  String text; // public field
}
```

```dart
for (var tab in tabs)
   Text(tab.text)
```

If the field `text` is private, you need to define a getter as follows:

```dart
class Tab {
  String _text; // private field

  // getter
  String get text => _text;
  // alternatively but ugly
  // String get getText => _text;
}
```

```dart
for (var tab in tabs)
   Text(tab.text)
```